# Dataframe Sort and Selection is not working

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am doing an assignment and I just cannot achieve a basic step.

I have joined 3 Dataframes energy, GDP and ScimEn as shown below.

Now on the merged Dataframe, I want to Sort and only the Top 15 Countries (On Rank().

I have tried everything but when I try a Sort or Rank < 16 or Rank <=15 operation, I always get a Key Error. Please help.

Whether I use line (a) or line (b), I keep getting an error.

```
df2 = pd.merge(energy, GDP, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df3 = pd.merge(df2, ScimEn, how='outer', left_index=True, right_on='Country')

df3 = df3.sort(['Rank'], ascending=[True])  --> (a)
df3 = df3[df3['Rank']<16]                   --> (b)

df3.head()
```

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? `df.sort` has been deprecated in favour of `df.sort_values`.

Comment: Also have you checked that `Rank` is definitely a column in df3? If `Rank` existed in 2 or more of the dataframes which were merged, then pandas automatically renames them as `Rank_x` and `Rank_y`